# Characterize a function given the average and the median

Tags: functions, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, average, median

How to 
(1) obtain some examples for an $f$ function and/or 
(2) characterize the whole set of $f$ functions 
which has the following properties given $m$ ($\leftarrow$ the *median*) that $0 < m < 1$ ($\leftarrow$ the *average*):

- $f\colon [-1, 1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$
- differentiable
- monotonically increasing
- $f(0) = m$
- $\int_{-1}^1 f(x) = 2$

For $m = 1$ we would have $f(x) = 1$ or $f(x) = x + 1$ as a trivial solution.

For the non-differentiable case we would have

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}m, & \text{if $x <= 0$}\\
2-m, & \text{if $x > 0$}\end{cases}$$

as a trivial solution.

I would be happy with some examples to some values of $m < 1$ (e.g. $m=\frac12$).

Any additional constraint can be applied if it makes the task easier (e.g. the shape of $f$ should resemble to a specific right skewed distribution).

Comment: You just characterized it… Hint for (1): assume $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. What properties does a,b,c need to have? Can you satisfy all the constraints at once (yes you can)?

Comment: Thank you @Eric! Taking into account that the graph is pushed to the left by $1$ and letting $b = 1$ we need $\int_{-1}^1 a(x+1)^2 + c = 2$. After doing the integration it follows that $c = 1 - \frac43a$. So our function is $f(x) = a(x+1)^2 + 1 - \frac43a$. Letting e.g. $a = \frac12$ we will have a nice example (for $m = \frac56$): $f(x) = \frac{(x+1)^2}2 + \frac13$. Am I right?

Comment: [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfrlw.png) for $f(x) = \frac{(x+1)^2}2 + \frac13$ on $[-1, 1]$.